# Calculating Effect Size for Generalized Linear Models

Tags: generalized-linear-model, sas, effect-size

I have measured spore production by a parasite after feeding the host on 4 diets of varying nutritional content. I have primarily analyzed the data by treating the diets as categorical variables, even though nutrient content is continuous. Most of the response variables are not normally distributed, so I have primarily used generalized linear models. I have found significant effects of host diet nutrient content on total number of infectious spores produced, the maximum rate of spore production, and duration of spore production (infectious period). SO, this raises the question of whether the effect of diet on total number of spores is due more to effects on duration of spore production, or on maximum rate of production.

I would like to compare the effect size of each model (maximum rate = diet Vs. duration = diet). For duration, calculating various measures of effect size was easy because I used PROC GLM and a typical ANOVA and simply included "EFFECTSIZE" in the model statement. Maximum rate however was analyzed using PROC GLIMMIX and a gamma distribution (not a mixed model though). My question is this: how can I calculate a measure of effect size that is comparable between those 2 models?

short version: I would like to compare effect size between a general linear model and a generalized linear model.

EDIT: Another possibility is to compare the models total = duration Vs. total = max rate, but I feel uncomfortable with that because it is divorced from my actual treatments.